# button click jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should be a really simple answer but I can't figure it out right now. I have this button:

```
<button id="logout" type="button">Logout</button>
```

And it's supposed to run this jQuery code within script tags at the bottom of the body:

```
$("#logout").addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

However, no alert pops up. I don't get it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `addEventListener` is a method of `DOM` element not of `jQuery` object which is an array-like structure that contains all the selected DOM elements

To attach event using `jQuery`, use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) => *Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements*

Try this:

```js
$("#logout").on("click", function() {
  alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="logout" type="button">Logout</button>
```

**Using JS:**

```js
document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

```html
<button id="logout" type="button">Logout</button>
```

**Edit:** You can get first `DOM element` from array-like object returned by `jQuery selector` using `$(SELECTOR)[0]` or `$(SELECTOR).get(0)`

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener()` method registers the specified listener on the `EventTarget`.

If you really want to use `addEventListener` then write the following code:

```
var el = document.getElementById("logout");
el.addEventListener("click", function () {
     alert('Button Clicked');
}, false);
```

Otherwise do it with jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "#logout", function () {
    alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

OR

```
$("#logout").on("click", function () {
        alert('Button Clicked');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate answer is:

```
$(document).on("click", "#logout", function() {
  alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

This works on dynamically created elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) method to use the event handlers in jquery. The addEventListener is a core JavaScript event method.

```
$("#logout").on("click", function() {
  alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

You may still use addEventListner forcing jQuery code to JavaScript:

```
$("#logout")[0] //Now, this is JavaScript Object
   .addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery click/on function for getting the button to work.

Example:

```
$("#logout").on("click", function () { alert('Button Clicked'); });
$("#logout").click(function () { alert('Button Clicked'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#logout").on("click", function () {
            alert('Button Clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="logout" type="button">Logout</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById("logout");

element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

     // your code logic comes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your console like in firebug and type `$()` you will see the jQuery object that shows the methods and properties of the jquery function/object. There is no addEventListener on this object.

`addEventlistener` is a method for the DOM. If you want to take advantage of jQuery by "writing less and do more" use jQuery methods like `on`. This will allow you to add an event handler on an element.

```
$(document).on("click", "#logout", function() {
  alert('button clicked');
});
```